# How can I remap topic cloud_in to my sensor's PointCloud2?

Tags: kinect, rviz, octomap, octomap-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi friends

I am new in ROS and I want do 3D map with my Kinect, I think a good option is with octomap_server, but I don't get it.

I think the easiest way would be using rviz but I can not get it. I think I must remap topic cloud_in to my sensor but I am not sure if it is going to run and I dont know the way to get it.

Does anybody know a tutorial? Help me please.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168776/how-can-i-remap-topic-cloud_in-to-my-sensor%27s-pointcloud2-???/) by [Rookie92](https://answers.ros.org/users/18371/rookie92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2014-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can remap "your pointCloud2 input" topic to cloud_in, by including following lines to your launch file,

e.g., if you are using this file:  octomap_mapping / octomap_server / launch / octomap_mapping.launch
write,

```
  <remap from="cloud_in" to="/(point cloud topic) />
```

under

(RGBD slam is also a nice option for mapping using kinect.)

---

Originally posted by [Sudeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/9671/sudeep/) with karma: 460 on 2014-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1